# How to hold inputs from the user into an array?

Tags: java, arrays

My java assignment consists of creating the board game called Qwixx. There are four classes in addition to the driver class used to create the game. In the Qwixx class, I need to create a constructor that has a parameter of a String array which serves to hold the name of the players.

Here is the Qwixx class:

```
public class Qwixx {
private String[] Players;

//constructor
public Qwixx(String[] Players) {

for (int i = 0; i<Players.length; i++) 
    Players[i] = null; //here is my problem where I don't quite know how to 
                       //fill this array with the names from the Driver 
  }                    //class
}
```

Here is the Driver class:

```
public class Driver {
   public static void main(String[] args) {

   Scanner myKey = new Scanner(System.in);

   System.out.print("Please enter the number of players (2-5): ");
    numPlayers = myKey.nextInt();

   for (int i = 1; i<= numPlayers; i++) {
        System.out.print("Please enter the name of player" + i + ": ");
        String name = myKey.next();

        Player joueur = new Player(); //for every player, an object must be
        joueur.name = name;          //created for the Player class
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the Player class:

```
public class Player { 
 public String name;

//default constructor
Public Player() {
name = null;
//initialization of other instance variables 
}

//constructor
Public Player(String playerName) {
name = playerName; }
}
```

Please help me figure out how to hold the name, inputted by the user from the Driver class, into the array of the Qwixx class. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: In `Driver` you can store all names into a `String[]` and then give it to the `Qwixx` constructor.

Comment: Why are you giving just the _names_ of the players to the `Qwixx` class? Why not the `Player`s themselves?  You're creating a `Player` for each name that you input, but you're never doing anything with it.  Why not save those `Player`s in an array and have your `Qwixx` constructor take that `Player[]` instead of a `String[]`.

Comment: A `List` is nearly always going to be more practical in cases like this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
    public class Driver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner myKey = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Please enter the number of players (2-5): ");
        int numPlayers = myKey.nextInt();

        //  Player joueur[]= new Player[numPlayers]; // Initializing the Player Objects
        String playerNames[] = new String[numPlayers];  // String Array to store Player Names

        for (int i = 0; i < numPlayers; i++) {
            System.out.print("Please enter the name of player" + i + ": ");
            String name = myKey.next();

            //      joueur[i].name = name;          // Do you really need Player objects to do some other tasks? if yes uncomment this.
            playerNames[i] = name;
        }
        Qwixx qwixx = new Qwixx(playerNames);

        String testNames[] = qwixx.getPlayerNames();

        for (String test : testNames) {
            System.out.println(test);
        }
        // Some other code
    }
}

      class Qwixx {

         private String[] Players;

        public Qwixx() {

    }
//constructor

    public Qwixx(String[] Players) {

        this.Players = new String[Players.length];
        //  System.arraycopy(Players, 0, this.Players, 0, Players.length); 
   // You can use this method System.arraycopy instead of the below for loop.   

        for (int i = 0; i < Players.length; i++) {
            this.Players[i] = Players[i];
        }
    }

    public String[] getPlayerNames() {
        return this.Players;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, your help is greatly appreciated!!